Determining linear boolean functions from a Karnaugh map
I'm currently working with Karnaugh maps and I'm not completely really sure how boolean linear functions can be determined by looking at the K-map.
As I understand it (by looking at the Wikipedia definitions found in this stack exchange post) and from the definitions of linear functions, the only boolean functions that are linear are the ones that have a checkerboard pattern in the K-map (as long as $f(0) = 0$).
See the two following K-maps (empty squares are output 0):

Is it true that these are the only possible linear boolean functions, or are there other cases where the functions can be linear as well? If so, how would I determine that?
I can find other functions that are edge cases such as

since $f(x) = x_1$, but then I guess it's due to the variables $x_2, x_3, x_4$ being redundant and that it can be reduced to a function of one variable.
